# Bot doesn't have permission for KICK/BAN Command

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, discord.js

So I've been learning a bit of js and discord.js and so I'm creating my bot. I seem to have problems regarding KICK/BAN Commands because of permissions. Now, when I invited bot to server, I've given him all permissions, and I also moved his role UP in the roles hierarchy in the server. What would be the problem?

This is the code :

```
if (message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS'])) {
        if(message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ban')) {
            let member = message.mentions.members.first();
            if (member)
                member.ban().then((member) => {
                    message.channel.send(":name_badge: " + member.displayName + " has been banned!")})
            else
                    message.channel.send("Make sure to @mention who you want to be banned!");
        }
    }
```

This is the error :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (D:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:7468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either 
by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was 
not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, 
use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It depends on who you are trying to ban. If the user you are trying to ban is an Administrator or server owner then it will not work and you'll get the error like you got here.

Comment: Yes! But how could I check that? Apparently, the guy that i tried this on was not admin or owner, But in the hyerarchy roles, he was highest, but without BAN or KICK permissions.. hmm

Comment: Is your bot an Administrator? Or does it only have the permissions for ban/kick? If it's an admin, then it won't matter where it is at in the hierarchy roles as long as the user you're trying to kick is not an admin or owner. However if it's not an admin and only has the required permissions, then it's role will need to be above whoever it is trying to kick. I don't believe there is any way to check if the bot is able to kick the user, you'll just have to add a catch() to your promise chain for banning and handle cases where it wasn't able to kick them there.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error and send a message which lets the user know that the person couldn't be kicked:

```js
//...
member.kick(reason)
  .then(() => {
    //...
  })
  .catch(err => {
    //...
  });
```

You can also check if the user is an administrator:

```
if (message.guild.member(member).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
  //...
}
```